# Swift : User ability to post either text or image in a tableview feed with one button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I'm new comer to the SOF and to swift and I've learn a lot reading your awesome post.
My challenge:
I've added a **view controller with table view** and **one button tab bar "Post button"**
When users hit post **another view-controller appears**.
The tableview contain three cells for three options.

My Question is there a simpler way to let user add **text only** or **image only** or **both**  in **one view-controller** without creating 3 cells for each possible choice? as Twitter for example